# Crashlytics work with wrong api secret key

Tags: android, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have fabric.properties file with api key and api secret key in my project.
But crashlytics work without secret key or with wrong secret key. Why? I don't undestand for what secret key.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].